# Default Radio button value from Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have the following code which works great to store the value of the radio button and write to the database(HTML--> Javascript --> PHP).

Now i have a update modal and want to populate the radio button values of a previous record. I am not sure what i am doing wrong, but i can't get the default values for the radio button to show when the user hits update.

HTML

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="update_flag">Update Flag:</label>
            <br>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="update_flag" value="Yes">Yes</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="update_flag" value="Maybe">Maybe</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="update_flag" value="No">No</label>
        </div>
```

Javascript: The JSON.Parse returns a YES/NO/MAYBE and i've checked that it is returning it properly.

```
    function GetUserDetails(id) {

$("#hidden_user_id").val(id);
$.post("ajax/readUserDetails.php", {
       id: id
    },
    function (data, status) {
        // PARSE json data            
        var va = JSON.parse(data);  
        $("output[name=update_flag]:checked").val(va.flag);
     }
);
// Open modal popup
$("#update_user_modal").modal("show");}
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
    // include Database connection file
    include("db_connection.php");

    // check request
    if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['id']) != "")
    {
    // get  ID
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    // Get  Details
    $query = "SELECT flag,
    FROM list WHERE id = '$id'";
    if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    $response = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response = $row;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $response['message'] = "Data not found!";
    }
    // display JSON data
    echo json_encode($response);


     }

       else
     {
         $response['status'] = 200;
         $response['message'] = "Invalid Request!";
     }
```

Comment: why a downvote ?

Comment: you realize that this statement (as posted) will fail `$query = "SELECT flag,
    FROM list` - Unless you didn't post your full query for it.

Comment: you're also open to a serious sql injection.

Comment: that is not the complete SQL statement and to prevent sql injection i should assign the query to a variable ? Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `$("output[name=update_flag]:checked").val(va.flag);` is where it went wrong. You should try something like this:

```
$("input[name=update_flag][value=" + radioBtnValueToCheck + "]").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. That is exactly where i was wrong. Thank You !!